# Java abstract method with object as input parameter

Tags: java, abstract

I can make this code work without an object as input parameter for the abstract method. For example, if I make the input parameter for the `printInformation()` method in person and emp as `printInformation(int x)` it works.

The moment I make the input parameter as an object for `printInformation()` method as shown below, it throws an error

> emp is not abstract and does not override abstract method
>   printInformation(person) in person class emp extends person{ ^

```
abstract class person{
 abstract void printInformation(person p);
}

class emp extends person{
 emp(){
  System.out.println("This is a emp constructor");
 }
 void printInformation(emp e){
  System.out.println("This is an emp");
 }
}

class entity{
 public static void main(String args[]){
  emp employeeObject = new emp();
  employeeObject.printInformation(employeeObject);
 }
}
```

Comment: It's odd that `person.printInformation` requires another `person`. Shouldn't it be printing the information from the `person` instance being accessed? Also, Java convention is to start class names with an uppercase letter, e.g. `Person` and `Employee`.

Comment: mine is more of a concept question...i am still a newbie. Why can I override if the input parameter is not an object type? I can override it when it is of a primitive type like int...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interface has a function defined like this:

```
void printInformation(person p);
```

Your class has a function defined like this:

```
void printInformation(emp e);
```

Those are not the same functions.  Java considers the second one a new overloaded method, not an implementation of the method from the interface.  Since the class `emp` isn't declared abstract, but hasn't provided an implementation for the abstract method `void printInformation(person)`, it is erroneous.

Comment: I do not understand when you say they are not the same functions. Why can I override if the input parameter is not an object type? I can override it when it is of a primitive type like int...

Comment: Two functions with the same name that take different arguments are `NOT` the same function.

Comment: @jahroy....how can they be different arguments? Person is a superclass and emp is its subclass....also, you can refer a superclass variable to a subclass object.

Comment: @user547453 - In the case of `int` you are *overloading* the method--not *overriding* it. They are indeed separate functions due to their signatures.

Comment: emp != person  The fact that one is a subclass of the other is irrelevant in this situation.  We're talking about the definition of a method, not the invocation of a method.

Comment: @user547453: Person is a superclass and emp is the subclass, yes. And that is why they are different functions, because the types `person` and `emp` are not the same type.  They are closely related, but different.  To be properly implemented, you need a `printInformation` function that can take a `person` argument.  You don't have one, you only have a `printInformation` function that can take an `emp`.  That means someone who calls you with a `person` instance won't find an implementation they can use.

Comment: @user547453   Jahroy hit it right on the head.  When you declare a method to take a certain set of parameters in an interface, you have to implement it with exactly those parameters (assuming you're not using generics, which you are not here).  As a side note, there's absolutely no reason to even take an argument to this function, since it should work on the object it's being called on.   Why would you have one person print information about another person.  Each person should print the information about itself.

Comment: Thanks to jahroy,Matt, Ned and David. Your answers were very valuable and I learnt well.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be doing something like this:

```
interface PrintsInformation<T> {
    void printInformation( T t );
}

class Emp implements PrintsInformation<Emp> {
    public void printInformation( Emp e ) {
        System.out.println( "This is an emp" );
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Emp employeeObject = new Emp();
    employeeObject.printInformation( employeeObject ); // compiles
}
```

The other way to fix your problem is to not pass in the object if it's printing itself.
Just do this:

```
    public void printInformation() {
        // print "this" object, rather than the one passed in
        System.out.println( "This is an emp" );
    }
```

Comment: great! but does this mean in Java I have to define an Interface to override abstract methods that take in Objects as input parameters?

Comment: You're not overriding a method if you're implementing another method with the same name that takes different parameters... That would be called `overloading`.  You can override abstract methods that take Objects as parameters... You just need to use the same parameters!

Comment: The only way you can change the argument types and still be considered to be implementing that same interface method is using generics, as is shown in this answer.  In the absence of generics, class hierarchies are not considered when determining if an interface method has been implemented.  You have to be exact.  That being said, since an employee is a person, any method implemented to accept a person will automatically be able to take an employee.  (google the liskov substitution principle)